# Android Studio 2.2.2 freezes when importing project into Team Services

Tags: android, android-studio, tfs

today I connected my Team Foundation Server with Android Studio. 
Since my decision was to start versioning the project, I tried to import my whole project into TFS.

After selecting the project where I want to import and clicking Import button it just froze the whole Studio.

[image: This screen freezes]

Comment: I have installed the same version Android Studio. It works perfect with my TFS15. Did you follow the tutorial in this link : https://java.visualstudio.com/docs/tools/androidstudio ?

Comment: Which version of TFS are you using？

Comment: Can you share the detailed steps so that we can try to reproduce the issue?

Comment: @Eddie-MSFT Well, I read about connecting with TFS, and the only steps I have did is clicking **VCS** tab, > **Import into version control**, and then Import into Team Services Git. Then I get the window, who I posted in the thread, and on the right side I connected to the local team server. After that it listed all my Projects. Then I selected in which project I want to import, after clicking Import it froze.

Comment: I have followed the same step as what you did. Still works well, the only thing difference is I have create git repository first. Did you do this thing as follow screenshot?

Comment: @Patrick-MSFT No, I created it on the administration panel in TFS.

Comment: Well you could give a try with my step. @FiN

Answer (score 0):

Please follow the tutorial link in VSTS:  [Android Studio](https://java.visualstudio.com/docs/tools/androidstudio)

And you can also **watch a how-to video** on importing projects on our [YouTube channel.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=D7bpC6KwrA4)

*Note: Also make sure you have enough permission with the team project in TFS which you want to import in.*

---

**Update**

[image]

---

[image]

Comment: It shows me only local directory to save the Git repository, but not on a remote location.

Comment: Yes, not on a remote location. Just your local computer with the folder stored your project and the folders and files to git. You should create a local git repository and then try to import your local repository into remote git repository. I guess

Comment: That's the situation...I need it in TFS, not Git.

Comment: Sorry that I've mislead you.  You can use this plugin to import your android development projects into your TFS **Git** repository. You are still import into the git repository not TFVC. So you should select a GIT team project in TFS. Did you import into a git team project in TFS?  And which version of TFS are you using?

Comment: I'm clicking "Import into Team Services Git", the button on your screenshot. After that I select the repository and click import. Then the whole android studio freezes.

My TFS  2015

Comment: Got it. It's really wired. Give a try with uninstall and reinstalled your plugin . And do you have enough permission to import code to your TFS project?

Comment: Yup, I even, I regularly push my code from the VS to the same TFS.

Comment: Have tried everything in my side. Still can't reproduce your issue......A suggest: Do you have a personal vsts account , try to import your local code from  Android Studio  to your vsts project...  This will narrow down the issue : If you also can't import successfully , then the issue may related to the plug-in or and Android Studio, if you can import successfully , the issue must related to the TFS server side.

Comment: Sorry for not replying for long time... I have personal VSTS, and I'm trying to get projects from it. I'm not trying to get projects from visual studio online.